# hover/ mouseenter/ mouseleave on menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to implement the following.

I have a navigation menu, where when I hover over the "Services" link a submenu is shown. The submenu stays shown if the cursor moves off "Services" in the main menu and hovers over the submenu and also if the cursor moves around the page. The submenu will disappear when one of the other main menu items is hovered over.

Example of the menu on this website (apologies for the link and I know the page may change soon, but showing as easiest way to describe what's required) https://kota.co.uk/

I am using WordPress

Example of the menu structure

HTML

```
<div class="slide-in-menu-container">
<div class="menu__main">
<a class="menu__block" href="/home">Home</a>
<a class="menu__services" href="/services">Services</a>
<a class="menu__block" href="/work">Work</a>
<a class="menu__block" href="/about">About</a>
<a class="menu__block" href="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="menu__services--hover">
<a href="/link">link</a>
<a href="/link">link</a>
<a href="/link">link</a>
<a href="/link">link</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have not shown any jQuery, as I have tried a few different solutions and didn't know which was best to show if any, but none of them keep the submenu shown until I hover over another menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially `hide()` your services div and we can achieve this by using jQuery `mouseover()` and `mouseleave()`

Run snippet below to see in action.

```js
$(".menu__services").mouseover(function() {
 $('.menu__services--hover').removeClass('d-none')
  $(".menu__block").mouseover(function() {
    $('.menu__services--hover').addClass('d-none')
 });
   });
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide-in-menu-container">
  <div class="menu__main">
    <a class="menu__block" href="/home">Home</a>
    <a class="menu__services" href="/services">Services</a>
    <a class="menu__block" href="/work">Work</a>
    <a class="menu__block" href="/about">About</a>
    <a class="menu__block" href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu__services--hover d-none">
    <a href="/link">link</a>
    <a href="/link">link</a>
    <a href="/link">link</a>
    <a href="/link">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite right yet. Hovering over the "Services" link the submenu is shown, but if I move the cursor directly to another menu link, the submenu is still shown, the submenu should disappear when hovering over another menu link. Additionally, after hovering on the submenu, as soon as you leave the container, the submenu disappears, it should be shown until you hover over another parent menu link.

Comment: @tonyd THanks for more clarification - I have updated my answer to match your expectations. Please let me know. There is not need to use `setTimeout` for this.

Comment: Almost there, once "services" has been hovered and the submenu appears, I need it to stay shown until another menu link is hovered over in the menu__main div. Similar to the example website in the original question.

Comment: @tonyd Please see my updated answer. I know what you mean. its working exactly as the website now.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping....Yes....all good, working as required, thank you very much!

Comment: @tonyd Good hear - Glad that i could help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just hide all menus when a mouse hovers on the other menu then show the menu you want to show and dont add function on mouseleve

Comment: Welcome to SO. Its ideal to provide a working solution in the answer instead of this explaining with statements.This way other members will benefit as well. Thanks. Read more about how to answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @alpha-wolf-gamer but I want to show the parent menu and the submenu at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer by @AlwaysHelping, There is a problem when mouse leave from main menu option, the sub menus panel not hiding, so i just corrected and putted a hack for that issue.

it will check main and submenus has already mousehover then it will not add class class for `d-none`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu__services").mouseenter(function() {
        $('.menu__services--hover').removeClass('d-none')
    });

    $(".menu__services, .menu__services--hover").mouseleave(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!$('.menu__services:hover').length && !$(".menu__services--hover:hover").length){
                $(".menu__services--hover").addClass('d-none')
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide-in-menu-container">
  <div class="menu__main">
    <a class="menu__block" href="/home">Home</a>
    <a class="menu__services" href="/services">Services</a>
    <a class="menu__block" href="/work">Work</a>
    <a class="menu__block" href="/about">About</a>
    <a class="menu__block" href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu__services--hover d-none">
    <a href="/link">link</a>
    <a href="/link">link</a>
    <a href="/link">link</a>
    <a href="/link">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the submenu stays visible even when hovering over other parent menu items.

Comment: Actually just checked the console and get an error _Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover_

Comment: Which Jquery version are you using?

Comment: I think you are using old jquery version or may browser issues thats why `is(":hover")` is not working, so i have updated answer check its working or not.

Comment: jQuery ver=1.12.4 and jquery-migrate.min.ver=1.4.1

Comment: Still the same console error. Have checked in Chrome and FF, both say Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

Comment: can  you add your jquery script link in your question..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216481/discussion-between-turivishal-and-tonyd).